# how to fix 'undefined reference to x' error when building u-boot , when the definition is compiled already but not linked

Tags: build, embedded-linux, u-boot

Of course I know what link error is and I've solved numerous 'undefined reference to ...' errors in the past.
Today I'm builing u-boot program and solved several 'undefined reference to ...' errors. While building u-boot, when the 'undefined' symbol is a function, there were two solutions.

1. make the function not called : by examining the .c source, sometimes the calling can be blocked by setting a config variable.  For exmpale mem_malloc_init is called only when CONFIG_SYS_SPL_MALLOC_START value is defined. But the result is reducing the functions of the final u-boot program (or u-boot-spl program) reducing the number of things we can do with the program.
2. make the related source compiled : by examining the Makefile, we can know what config condition makes the code compiled and later used in the linking.

However, in the example in 1), the source for the missing function mem_malloc_init actually exists in common/dlmalloc.c and common/Makefile has unconditiall `obj-y += dlmalloc.o` and the generated common/built-in.o contains the definition mem_malloc_init. I can check with `nm` command.
But the final command generating the 'undefined reference' errro to make spl/u-boot-spl is like this (see the bold) :

> ( cd spl && aarch64-none-elf-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles
> -fuse-linker-plugin -flto=28 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-format-security **-fno-builtin** -ffreestanding -std=gnu11 -    fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-PIE -Os  -flto=28
> -fno-stack-protector -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds     -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -g -fstack-usage -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-but-    set-variable -Werror=date-time -Wno-packed-not-aligned  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-stack-protector -D__KERNEL__ -D__UBOOT__  -DCONFIG_SPL_BUILD  -D__ARM__              -mstrict-align  -fno-common -ffixed-r9  -mgeneral-regs-only    -fno-common -ffixed-x18 -pipe -march=armv8-a+crc -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=8   -Ispl/include -Iinclude   -I./arch/ar    m/include -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/arm-toolchains/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.2.1/include
> -Wl,-T -Wl,u-boot-spl.lds -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-dynamic-linker -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,-Ttext -Wl,0x4000000 arch/arm/cpu/armv8/start.o -Wl    ,--whole-archive arch/arm/cpu/armv8/built-in.o arch/arm/cpu/built-in.o
> arch/arm/lib/built-in.o board/etri/ab21m/built-in.o
> **common/spl/built-in.o** common/init/built-in.o disk/bui    lt-in.o
> drivers/built-in.o dts/built-in.o fs/built-in.o  keep-syms-lto.o -L
> /opt/arm-toolchains/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.
> 2.1 -lgcc -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-Map,u-boot-spl.map **-o u-boot-spl** )

The link command requires common/spl/built-in.o for the link but I can't find any .o file under common/spl. (instead, under common/ I see many .o files and built-in.o file : these are for u-boot proper program) The  common/dlmalloc.c is the only place mem_malloc_init is defined.
So, my question becomes : why aren't the source files under common/spl compiled(eventhough the common/spl directory is included as obj-y in common/Makefile)? and why isn't the common/built-in.o file included in linking the spl/u-boot-spl?

Comment: I've removed the remaining link errors by setting CONFIG_SPL_LIBGENERIC_SUPPORT and CONFIG_SPL_LIBCOMMON_SUPPORT. Someone (Ovidiu Panait from windriver) in the u-boot email list told me that. So I guess it's mostly configure thing.

Comment: In my case I installed missing packages sudo apt-get install bc bison build-essential coccinelle device-tree-compiler dfu-util efitools flex gdisk graphviz imagemagick  liblz4-tool libgnutls28-dev libguestfs-tools libncurses-dev   libpython3-dev libsdl2-dev libssl-dev lz4 lzma lzma-alone openssl   pkg-config python3 python3-asteval python3-coverage python3-filelock  python3-pkg-resources python3-pycryptodome python3-pyelftools python3-pytest python3-pytest-xdist python3-sphinxcontrib.apidoc  python3-sphinx-rtd-theme python3-subunit python3-testtools  python3-virtualenv swig uuid-dev

Comment: In case of using TPL, also set CONFIG_TPL_LIBCOMMON_SUPPORT=y and CONFIG_TPL_LIBGENERIC_SUPPORT=y, it fixes all the link errors related to dynamic memory (malloc, calloc, free)